# How to get number of tomcat requests which duration less than 1 sec or 5 sec

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm trying to find out how to get the number of tomcat requests by their duration.
I've installed [JWM Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter) and have a lot of metrics, but can't imagine how to calculate what I want.

Seems **tomcat_requestcount_total / ( tomcat_processingtime_total / 60 )** somehow helps, but not sure - looks like it's a average time in seconds to each requests.

Here is the list of available metrics related to tomcat:

tomcat_bytesreceived_total
tomcat_bytessent_total
tomcat_errorcount_total
tomcat_maxtime_total
tomcat_processingtime_total
tomcat_requestcount_total
tomcat_servlet_errorcount_total
tomcat_servlet_maxtime_total
tomcat_servlet_processingtime_total
tomcat_servlet_requestcount_total
tomcat_session_expiredsessions_total
tomcat_session_processingtime_total
tomcat_session_rejectedsessions_total
tomcat_session_sessioncounter_total
tomcat_threadpool_connectioncount
tomcat_threadpool_currentthreadcount
tomcat_threadpool_currentthreadsbusy
tomcat_threadpool_keepalivecount
tomcat_threadpool_pollerthreadcount

Comment: Is there `tomcat_requestcount_bucket` metric? If so, what `le` labels does it have.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such metric.

Answer (score 0):

As a result, no need to install/run an additional exporter in order to get mentioned metrics. Such metric, **jira_request_duration_on_path_bucket**, provided by default  [Prometheus Exporter for Jira](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1222502/prometheus-exporter-for-jira?tab=overview&hosting=server), but in my case, I have an issue in prometheus.yml file, so that's why I don't see needed metric.